# shell command: join crashes for large files?

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files; `1.txt` and `2.txt`

`1.txt` has the following content:

```
a 1 2 3 4 5
b 4 5 6 7 7
c 4 5 6 7 6
d 6 5 4 3 2
```

and `2.txt`;

```
b
d
```

I need to extract those lines from `1.txt` whose first fields match the first fields of `2.txt`;

```
b 4 5 6 7 7
d 6 5 4 3 2
```

I thought a simple join command should work for me:

```
join 1.txt 2.txt
```

But unfortunately, the command produces just a couple of lines, even though both files are pretty large.

I cannot figure out what's going on.

Comment: Did you sort first?  I wouldn't call this crashing.  What is `$?` after running ?

Comment: yes, both sorted.

Comment: That test data *will* only give two lines of output. If you want debugging help, you're supposed to provide the smallest example that exhibits the problem. Your data doesn't *actually* exhibit a problem.

Comment: or if you execute `head -5 file1 file2 | cat -vet` and see `^M$` at the end of each line, the use `dos2unix file1 file2` to remove `\r` chars (DOS line endings). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter -- Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it. It didn't help. Maybe something with char encoding?